# How to put a Char type into STDIN in JDOODLE by Pascal?

Tags: jdoodle

I would like to ask related to JDOODLE, how can I give any parameter of char type in the STDIN window for the language Pascal? Shall I use quotations or apostrophes?

Pascal: readln(character);
STDIN : c
Shall I use c or 'c' or "c" ?

For all three I receive the "Runtime roor 106" (Wrong input type)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I figured  it out: In JDOODLE the Pascal compiler can't read multiple  inputs from console. I had to write the inputs in separated readln-s, that way works.